# Ajax always return a data but no data in alert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am trying to save a videoId with email of the user by using ajax and php , the problem is in the addDuration.php where i add the videoId and email the function work fine but the ajax funtion return an empty data wehn i try to alert it it always alert with empty box.

script.js where i call the funtion

```
function initVideo(videoId,clientEmail){
    startHideTimer();
    updateProgressTimer(videoId,clientEmail);

}

function updateProgressTimer(videoId,clientEmail){
    addDuration(videoId,clientEmail);
}

function addDuration(videoId,clientEmail){

    $.post("ajax/addDuration.php",{videoId: videoId, clientEmail: clientEmail},function(data){
        if(data !==null && data !==""){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
```

addDuration.php where i am saving the data to the DB

```
<?php

require_once("../../includes/config.php");

    if(isset($_POST["videoId"]) && isset($_POST["clientEmail"])){
        $clientEmail=$_POST["clientEmail"];
        $videoId=$_POST["videoId"];
        $query=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM videoprogress 
                            WHERE clientEmail=:clientEmail AND videoId=:videoId");
        $query->bindValue(":clientEmail",$clientEmail);
        $query->bindValue(":videoId",$videoId);
    
        $query->execute();
    
    
        if($query->rowCount()==0){
            $query=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO videoprogress(clientEmail,videoId) VALUES (:clientEmail,:videoId)");
            $query->bindValue(":clientEmail",$clientEmail);
            $query->bindValue(":videoId",$videoId);
    
            $query->execute();
    
        }
    
    }else{
        echo "nothing is passed !";
    }
    
    ?>
```

config.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Tunis");


try{
    $con= new PDO("mysql:dbname=cinecad;host=localhost","root","");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

}catch(PDOException $e){
    exit("Connexion failed:".$e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

every time the page refreshed

```
<script>
    initVideo("<?php echo $video->getId();?>","<?php  echo $email;?>");
</script>
```

Comment: What does your PHP code output when everything works properly?  Nothing.  So that is what you get in your alert box.  (data probably equals undefined which is neither null nor "")

Comment: it's alert too with empty box always

Comment: Your PHP needs to output something on success, if you want the alert to contain something.

Comment: I did  echo "true" but always empty box

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
echo 'Some success message or result here';
```

Inside your addDuration.php file in the IF statement just before the ELSE block.

Comment: I did but the data will output Some success message or result here but with another echo not sure where it came from